# tictactoe and copying an array

Tags: c++

Hello I am working on a tic-tac-toe project on my own. I am not taking a programming class so its not homework.

I have written pretty much the rest of the code and am now working on the AI.

For the AI i am going to have it take a copy of the  (2 dimensional array) and it check if it can win in a move, then if the player can, then if it can in 2 moves, then the player and so on,  there are some other things i will include. So in order to do this i think i need to pass a copy of the array, but i am not sure how to copy an array. So that is basically my question, how do you copy an array?

Comment: Is there a reason you selected an array ahead of `std::vector<std::vector<type>>`?

Comment: well i'm new to programming and i haven't gotten into vectors yet, although i have heard of them. Would you recommend them over arrays?

Comment: @hmjd: Since the board has fixed, statically known size, a dynamic data structure seems inappropriate.

Comment: No, if the size is more or less small and the size is a compile time constant arrays are perfectly fine. (And much faster than vectors for each dimension after the first.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the array into a class, in which case it'll be copied automatically by the default-generated copy constructor and assignment operator:

```
enum EField { empty, cross, oh };

typedef std::array<EField, 9> TTTBoard;  // C++11, or use std::tr1::array
```

Or do it manually:

```
struct TTTBoard
{
    EField data[9];   // or even EField data[3][3]
};
```

Now you can copy it at will:

```
TTTBoard b;
TTTBoard c = b;
```

Comment: i get the last part with struct, but i don't quite know what enum is or typedef.

Comment: +1 As far as question regarding `std::vector` I was concerned with ease of copying only.

Comment: @PatrickKennedy: once you spend a few more hours reading your favourite C++ book, you will surely have the answers to those questions!

Answer (score 3):

A neat trick you could do without concerning yourself with array copying is to create a type for your 3x3 board:

```
 struct TicTac{
    int board[3][3];
 }
```

And just pass that as the argument to your function.

Comment: hmm ok, would it be easier to copy?

Comment: @PatrickKennedy This way the copying is done automatically as Kerrek hints at.

Comment: ahh i see, thanks that clarifies that. So i would just pass the object and it would be automatically copied. But would that mean i would have to pass its address when i don't want a copy?

Comment: @PatrickKennedy Yes, but don't frown upon copies unless you really need to change the source. `void f(TicTac &boardThatCanBeChanged)`

Answer (score 1):

What kind of array do you have?
I'm assuming you have the plain old school integer array.

when you have:
    int Array[3][3];

then to copy it's contents to another array you will have to loop each element.
this can be done like this:

```
int MyArray[3][3];
int CopyHere[3][3];
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(MyArray); ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(MyArray[i]); ++j)
    {
        CopyHere[i][j] = MyArray[i][j];
    }
}
```

I have somewhere an old TicTacToe script, lemme look for it.

Edit: found it:

http://pastebin.com/Xp5iT2b0

Here is the related topic:

http://forum.sa-mp.com/showthread.php?t=259549